# Convert human dutch date string to date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, date-fns

I am using datefns to work with dates and I have the following date:

'05 okt 2022'

How can I convert this to a date object in javascript?

I have tried the following:

```
import { parse } from 'date-fns'
import {nl} from 'date-fns/locale';
parse('05 okt 2022', "dd MMM yyyy", new Date(), { locale: nl})
```

However this gives an invalid date.

Comment: How are you retrieving this date? Seems to me that it should be stored as a universal date format and only be changed to a locale string when displaying it, not the other way around.

Comment: I am using this library: https://litepie.com/ . Which forces me to chose a format, since it uses that format to display the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very convenient to use multiple libraries when working with dates, as usually each library has its own date pattern and format/parse rules. Seems that you want to use `date-fns` just to parse the date string generated by `litepie`, which is a bit overkill considering that it weights [26.8
kB minified+gzipped](https://bundlephobia.com/package/date-fns).
That parsing can be implemented in a few lines of code:

```js
// build the months names list, MMM
const months = new Map([...Array(12)]
    .map((x, i) => [new Date(2022, i, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        .toLocaleDateString('nl-NL', {month: 'short'}).slice(0, 3), i]));

const parse = date => {
    const i = date.split(' ');
    return new Date(i[2], months.get(i[1].slice(0, 3)), i[0]);
};

console.log(parse('05 okt 2022').toString());
console.log(parse('08 mrt 2022').toString());
```